# Form data won't add and MySql table remains empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know this is not a safe way for inserting data into mysql but this is just for example! Please this script is not adding any data into mysql table with these fields:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['c_id']) || !isset($_SESSION['sid']) ||!isset($_SESSION['ip'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<?php
$cid1= $_POST['hiddencid'];
$update= $_POST['hiddenupdate'];
$time = strftime("%b %d %Y %X");

mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx') or die(mysql_error());    
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT into newsfeed (cid,update,time) values ('$cid1','$update','$time')");


echo "Profile Updated";

?>
```

Comment: Fix your sql injections.

Comment: Oh look, yet another PHP/MySQL question with [major security problems](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Briedis and Quentin: Magic Quotes to the rescue!

Answer (score 3):

Your column name update is a reserved word and need special treatment. Use double quotes with ANSI SQL mode enabled, or back ticks.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html.

```
INSERT into newsfeed (cid,`update`,time) values ('$cid1','$update','$time');
```

Comment: Thankyou JK I just realised that and was able to solve the problem =]

Answer (score 0):

One important thing is that you should take care of reserved MySql statements. The next thing is that you should add a `or die(mysql_error())` after your `mysql_query()`. As you didn't use it, you didn't receive a mysql error.

Then reformat your query to:

```
INSERT INTO `newsfeed` (`cid`,`update`,`time`) VALUES ('$cid1','$update','$time')
```

Remember: `update` and `time` are reserved statements.

Comment: Thnku FlyBy I was able to solve the problem too just yest. =] and well i do use or die(mysql_error()) ... this query was just an example